# How to set visudo to use a different editor than the default on Fedora?

Tags: sudo

Fedora 14 uses vi by default when one runs visudo. Is there a way to change this to something else?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Adding `Defaults editor=/path/to/editor` in the sudoers file will cause visudo to use the specified editor for changes.

Additionally, if your sudo package has been built with --with-env-editor, as is the default on some Linux distributions, you can also set the EDITOR environment variable by executing `export EDITOR=/path/to/editor`. Performed on the command line this will revert as soon as that shell session is terminated, setting the variable in a ~/.bashrc or /etc/profile will cause the change to persist.

Comment: Could you please provide the command(s) that you executed?

Comment: @Tshepang - You can also set Defaults editor=/usr/bin/nano in the sudoers file to specify an editor. At this point I am assuming that you wish to use nano as specified in your earlier comment.

Comment: @Tshepang - Yes, however, this is likely a product of having built the package using --with-env-editor.

Comment: @Tok: On what system doesn't `visudo` honor `$VISUAL` and `$EDITOR`?

Comment: @Gill It is Fedora 14 default install.

Comment: @Tshepang: Yes, I was wondering what system is *not* like this. (Debian, Fedora, Ubuntu, OpenBSD have `sudo` honoring `VISUAL` and `EDITOR`.)

Comment: @Gilles - based on my reading Ubuntu has recently changed the build parameters of their sudo package to not include `--with-env-editor`, recently here meaning within the memory of the internet. Additionally the sudo package changed their default some time ago to use vi as their default editor which I believe coincided with a change to the behavior regarding the acceptance of environmental variables. I do not have a clear timeline of how, when, or if these events relate to each other at this time.

Comment: @gilles: On RHEL 5.10, which I use, visudo doesn't honor $VISUAL or $EDITOR.

Comment: @Gilles I'm using Arch Linux and sudo does not honor `$EDITOR` nor `$VISUAL` env var either. I have to add the variable after sudo to manually override it.

Comment: @FranklinYu Note that this is about `visudo`, not about `sudo`. If you run `sudo visudo`, then `visudo` never gets a chance to honor `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` because it doesn't see them. You need to write something like `sudo EDITOR=emacs visudo`.

Comment: `sudo EDITOR=/usr/bin/vi visudo` is what I used to get this to work.

Comment: If you have the `$EDITOR` variable set in your user's environment you can use `sudo -E visudo` to get it into your sudo environment (it will share *all* environment variables and may have security implications). This works for me on Arch.

Answer (score 22):

The following

- works for distros that use `alternatives` (originally just Debian and its forks, but now most major distros, IIUC).
- has the advantage that

  1. you won't need to edit `sudoers` first with its default editor
  2. it works even if package=`sudo` has *not* been built with `--with-env-editor`

From a commandline:

1. Run `sudo update-alternatives --config editor`
2. Choose desired editor from the (text-mode) menu. If you don't see the editor you want, you probably need to install it; cancel, do that, and repeat.

`sudo visudo` should now open the editor of your choice.

Comment: This worked for ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 15):

`visudo` uses the `EDITOR` variable, for example.

```
sudo EDITOR=/path/to/editor visudo
```

Comment: This is excellent. It gets around the circular problem of using the default editor to change the default edit.

Comment: It's certainly a reasonable solution, but IMHO, it misses the point because you have to use this command each time the `sudo` file is edited. Other answers here propose changes to default behavior.

Comment: @Seamus, While I agree with your statement, I was stuck with how to do this the very first time (before changing the default in the sudo file).  So this answer combined with the accepted answer which included adding `Defaults editor=/path/to/editor ` to the sudoers file.

Answer (score 10):

A normal unix program that wants to invoke an editor will run the program whose name is in the `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variable, and if the variable is unset, a system-dependent default. Many, but not all, programs check both `EDITOR` and `VISUAL`; the distinction is long obsolete (once you would run `EDITOR` on a teletype and `VISUAL` on a “glass” terminal…) so you should set both to the same value. There is some disagreement as to whether the contents of the variable should be the full path to an executable, an executable name that's looked up in `$PATH`, or a shell snippet, so you should stick to a path to an executable not containing any shell metacharacter. The system default when neither variable is set is traditionally `vi`, though some distributions have changed this to a more newbie-friendly editor such as `nano`.

`visudo` checks both `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` (this can be compiled out, presumably to dissuade root from using an editor whose security the distribution maker doesn't trust, but even OpenBSD doesn't do this).

Answer (score 6):

**These steps let me set the editor to vi for visudo on Ubuntu 12.04, they may work for other distributions:**

Issue command:

```
sudo visudo
```

This opens up the sudoers file in nano.  Near the top you will see this line:

```
Defaults    env_reset
```

Add the following line beneath the above line:

```
Defaults    editor=/usr/bin/vi
```

Save the file and exit.  Reopen visudo as your default user:

```
sudo visudo
```

The sudoers file now opens up in VI.

Answer (score 1):

IMPO the best way to do this is to have each user set their own preferred editor using the `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables in their own `.bashrc` file (or the equivalent for their preferred shell), then tell `sudo` to respect those variables.

So you would add this to `/etc/sudoer` using `visudo`:

```
## Respect the user's choice of editors
Defaults env_keep += "EDITOR VISUAL"
```

Then add this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
# e.g. if you want to use micro
EDITOR=micro
VISUAL=micro
```

For the distinction between `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` and why I think it's best to set both, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/visual-vs-editor-what-s-the-difference).

---

After this `sudo visudo` should use the user's preferred editor for all users.