# VISUAL vs. EDITOR – what’s the difference?

Tags: environment-variables, editors

I generally set both `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` environment variables to the same thing, but what's the difference? Why would I set them differently? When developing apps, why should I choose to look at `VISUAL` before `EDITOR` or vice versa?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

The `EDITOR` editor should be able to work without use of "advanced" terminal functionality (like old `ed` or `ex` mode of `vi`).  It was used on teletype terminals.

A `VISUAL` editor could be a full screen editor as `vi` or `emacs`.

E.g. if you invoke an editor through bash (using `C-x C-e`), bash will try first `VISUAL` editor and then, if `VISUAL` fails (because terminal does not support a full-screen editor), it tries `EDITOR`.

Nowadays, you can leave `EDITOR` unset or set it to `vi -e`.

Comment: Most applications treat `$VISUAL` as a shell snippet that they append the (shell-quoted) file name to, but some treat it as the name of an executable which they may or may not search in `$PATH`. So it's best to set `VISUAL` (and `EDITOR`) to the full path to an executable (which could be a wrapper script if you want e.g. options).

Comment: In modern times, `ed` and similar are not very popular so I believe it is OK to just ignore `VISUAL` and use `EDITOR`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `C-x C-e` in bash.  Very handy.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda, just setting `EDITOR` is not enough e.g. for `git` on Ubuntu 12.04. Without `VISUAL` being set `git` ignores `EDITOR` and just uses `nano` (the compiled in default, I guess).

Comment: @jacwah, this is why I wrote 'is not enough e.g. for git on Ubuntu 12.04'. I mentioned Ubuntu 12.04 as a concrete example where just setting EDITOR is not enough - at least when you are using git there. And this behavior matches the historical distinction correctly described by 'andcoz'.

Comment: @maxschlepzig Sloppy reading on my part...

Comment: @PavelŠimerda You're better off ignoring `EDITOR` and just using `VISUAL`, as the latter has better support and is the "correct" variable for modern usage.

Comment: @maxschlepzig I haven't experienced any issue with Git on any distribution but I wasn't using Ubuntu 12.04 to be honest.

Comment: @Zenexer I'm not convinced.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda It doesn't make sense, but it's the convention.  EDITOR used to be for instruction-based editors like `ed`.  When editors with GUIs came about--and by GUI, I mean CLI GUI (vim, emacs, etc.--think ncurses), not desktop environment GUI--the editing process changed dramatically, so the need for another variable arose.  In this context, CLI GUI and desktop environment GUI editors are more or less the same, so you can set VISUAL to either; however, EDITOR is meant for a fundamentally different workflow.  Of course, this is all historical.  Nobody uses ed these days.

Comment: I didn't question the history at all. I consider this whole discussion out of place. Repeating the same stuff all over will not convince me that `EDITOR` won't work for me when I've been using it with success for ages, nor does it convince me that `VISUAL` is still universally supported nowadays. If you don't have actual data, I'm not interested in continuing the discussion. And I'm certainly not interested in further cluttering the comment space under an answer on Stack Exchange by random chatting.

Comment: git gives higher priority to VISUAL than EDITOR. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596819/145349

So git uses EDITOR only is VISUAL isn't set

Answer (score 63):

The accepted answer is probably a good, short treatment, but this will be an attempt to go deeper on when the distinction between VISUAL and EDITOR might still matter (building on [Adam Katz's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/302391/208060)).

The POSIX spec still distinguishes between visual mode editors and line editors.  This really mattered back in the days when cursor positioning over serial connections was hard (especially because of the speed of the serial connection). The [Wikipedia article for vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) gives some useful background on the distinction between vi (a visual mode editor) and ex (a line editor).  If you dig deep enough down the research, you'll find [the "RATIONALE" section of the "ex" spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html#tag_20_40_18), which gives a reason for the distinction still being in the spec:

> It is recognized that portions of vi would be difficult, if not
> impossible, to implement satisfactorily on a block-mode terminal, or a
> terminal without any form of cursor addressing, thus it is not a
> mandatory requirement that such features should work on all terminals.
> It is the intention, however, that a vi implementation should provide
> the full set of capabilities on all terminals capable of supporting
> them.

I haven't needed this since giving up my 300 baud modem, but I can imagine that people who use slow serial lines to connect to embedded systems (and/or over really dicey connections) *might* still appreciate being able to have a preferred line mode editor distinct from a "visual" editor like vi.  VT100-style terminal codes over a lossy, laggy, narrow connection might be "bloat" in limited applications.

For the rest of us, it seems the "correct" answer seems to be "set them both to be your preferred editor".  It might be ok to co-opt this distinction for graphical editor (e.g. Sublime, gvim or emacs) vs a terminal editor (e.g. vi/vim or emacs with -nw option), but there's likely a mountain of legacy reasons why that probably won't work as hoped.

Answer (score 9):

`$VISUAL` is a more capable and interactive preference over `$EDITOR`. If undefined, anything seeking `$VISUAL` *should* then try `$EDITOR` next.

Some people have adopted a modern convention denoting `$VISUAL` as graphical and `$EDITOR` as an interactive terminal. Historically, `$VISUAL` (like [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)) referred to an interactive terminal display while `$EDITOR` (like [ed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_(text_editor))) was a line editor incapable of handling (text) cursor movement. See  [robla's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/334022/87770) for more historical notes.

At the moment, I have stuff like this in my `~/.bashrc` and `~/.zshrc`:

```bsh
# Prefer vim or else fail over to vi
EDITOR="$(command -v vim 2>/dev/null || command -v vi)"

# we have gvim, not in an SSH term, and the X11 display number is under 10
if command -v gvim >/dev/null 2>&1 \
&& [ "$SSH_TTY$DISPLAY" = "${DISPLAY#*:[1-9][0-9]}" ]; then
  export VISUAL="$(command -v gvim) -f"
  SUDO_EDITOR="$VISUAL"
else
  SUDO_EDITOR="$EDITOR"
fi
```

`gvim` without `-f` won't work with programs that expect to act on your edits.  This definitely includes `sudoeditor` (`sudo -e`).

This may break if you have whitespace in the path to vim.  If that's a problem, either install it properly or else consider symlinks like `/usr/local/bin/gvim`

Comment: Whether to use `$VISUAL` depends whether you have a terminal capable of cursor positioning, not whether you have a window system available.

Comment: Ah, great! Can you provide a definitive reference link for that? I think my code is still safe since I'm also checking for `$DISPLAY`, but that's good to know.

Comment: Never mind, it appears such a references exists in [robla's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/334022/87770), which even mentions my answer.

Comment: Back when I wrote my 2016 answer, I didn't have enough reputation to write a comment (which I would have done).  Thanks for the writing prompt, @AdamKatz !

Answer (score 4):

Some tools only accept EDITOR, for example the shell builtin *fc*:

```
-e ENAME  select which editor to use.  Default is FCEDIT, then EDITOR, then vi
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there don't seem to be any environments where vi or similar would fail, I've taken to setting VISUAL to something that needs an X DISPLAY, and EDITOR to ex.

Mostly, that just seems to cause me problems when some program doesn't use VISUAL.

Comment: just be aware that this won't work with ssh. VISUAL means "tui" not X11, and many programs, like git, will assume the editor is being rendered through the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

**In general, you shouldn't have to worry** about EDITOR or VISUAL, because the default for EDITOR is "vi" and for VISUAL it is EDITOR.

- Only set EDITOR if you want stone cold *ex* or *ed*
- Set VISUAL only to override EDITOR and if a graphical environment exists and emacs, vim, nano etc. are installed

In short, if you really want to set these variables, **you have to have a good reason, because their concept is default-proof.** Don't bother and you always get *vi*. That's tough for younglings but this way there are no surprises *ever*. For example, on remote systems where you don't have your fancy tools and initialization files (.emacs .vimrc) and therefore would suffer, you are not really suffering because you get the reliable *vi*. Back on your own system you'll get *vi* too unless you set VISUAL.

BTW, both should be set in *$HOME/.bash_profile*, so only for login shells and only overridden in *$HOME/.bashrc* if (and only if) there are good reasons. The latter file is only executed for interactive shells, and each interactive shell can only be run under a login shell whose variables interactive shells inherit.

If you want to override them in *$HOME/.bashrc* then you most likely want to query the TERM variable ("dumb") and make sure DISPLAY is not empty (i.e. there is a graphical environment). This is one more reason not to worry about both variables and to leave it on your system with the defaults. Just learn to edit commit messages with vi and start your editor or IDE directly from the command line and you'll be fine.

But to really understand what's been said here and why the recommendation not to care about these variables was made, look at how Git uses these variables:

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/editor.c

All you need to know.

Comment: This is only true in systems that define these variables for you. In my Arch Linux install, (which I use, btw), neither are set out of the box. It then is left up to each program to decide what to do - and they don't always behave "correctly."