# How do I change the default text editor in the Debian (squeeze) distro

Tags: debian, environment-variables, editors

"Joe's own editor" does not come naturally to me. How do I change to using nano or vim?

I've tried

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

but it doesn't seem to be respected. I'd like `visudo` to respect this as well.

Comment: You're way should work but you have to manually export `EDITOR` each time you start the shell. Try this: `echo "export EDITOR=nano" >> ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, but it actually wasn't working at all. I'm not sure what the deal was b/c this works in other distros and environments for me.

Comment: @BryanDunsmore No, not to `~/.bashrc`, to `~/.profile`. See [Alternative to .bashrc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/3085#3085)

Comment: It noticed this is the default also in Debian GNU/Linux buster (current stable). At least in the version provided by the OVH service provider.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

To change the default editor at the system level:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

and then follow the onscreen prompts.

Comment: If your editor isn't on the list, do this first (for geany) `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/bin/geany 10`

Comment: This doesn't work for non-root users

Answer (score 22):

The way to change the default editor for your account *is* to set the `EDITOR` environment variable. If that doesn't work for you, you've done something unusual. Check that you haven't also defined `VISUAL`, or if you have, give the two variables the same value (see [VISUAL vs. EDITOR – what’s the difference?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/visual-vs-editor-whats-the-difference)). Add these lines to your `~/.profile` (note: [not to `~/.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085)):

```
EDITOR=nano
VISUAL=$EDITOR
export EDITOR VISUAL
```

Under the [Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#editors-and-pagers), all programs are supposed to support `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` to set the default editor.

Under Debian and derivatives, you can use the [alternatives mechanism](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) to set the system-wide default editor, [as mentioned by Steve Robillard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42727): run `update-alternatives --config editor` as root.

Comment: It is also changing an editor only for you, not for every user. There's a little possibility that someone may not be familiar with vim if you set it system-wide as default editor.

Comment: "Under the Debian policy, all programs are supposed to support EDITOR and VISUAL to set the default editor."  In a twist of irony, `editor` is not one of those commands. :/ https://stackoverflow.com/a/73307112/3196753

Comment: @tresf `editor` is the default to use when `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` are unset. There's a separate command which checks `EDITOR` and `VISUAL`, called `sensible-editor`. See the link for “Debian policy”.

Answer (score 19):

The solution mentioned above works, but it isn't scriptable. If you want to do this in a scriptable (non-interactive) fashion, you should use --set:

```
# update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/vim.basic
```

You can get a list of the choices with:

```
$ update-alternatives --list editor
```

Answer (score 4):

I came across the very same issue, however setting it via update-alternatives did not quite do the trick on a Raspbian Buster (10.2).
Although I set vim.basic as my default editor (manually using update-alternatives --config editor), it had only a priority 30, while nano had a priority of 40.

```
root@rsyslog:~/scripts# update-alternatives --config editor
There are 4 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /bin/nano            40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
* 3            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    15        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

I started poking around in the usual profile- and dot-files and came accross the following one:

```
root@rsyslog:~/scripts# cat /root/.selected_editor 
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/bin/nano"
root@rsyslog:~/scripts#
```

After setting vim.basic via **/usr/bin/select-editor**, the file contained vim.basic:

```
root@rsyslog:~/scripts# /usr/bin/select-editor

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  2. /usr/bin/vim.basic
  3. /usr/bin/vim.tiny
  4. /bin/ed

Choose 1-4 [1]: 2
root@rsyslog:~/scripts# cat /root/.selected_editor 
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim.basic"
root@rsyslog:~/scripts#
```

Upon now I could do crontab -e with VIM again :).