# How can I set "vi" as my default editor in UNIX?

Tags: vim, vi

I believe I can do something like `export EDITOR=vi`, but I'm not sure what exactly to enter, and where.

How can I set "vi" as my default editor?

Comment: just `export EDITOR=vim` in your bashrc or zshrc or ..rc

Comment: often must be set up for programs in addition to this such as git

Comment: In Ubuntu ([as said](http://superuser.com/a/281618/500826)), try run: `select-editor`.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

You should add it to your shell’s configuration file. For Bash, this is `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` (see [detailed comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile)). You should also set `$VISUAL`, as some programs (correctly) use that instead of `$EDITOR` (see [`VISUAL` vs. `EDITOR`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/visual-vs-editor-whats-the-difference)). Additionally, unless you know why, you should set it to `vim` instead of `vi`.

TL;DR, add the following to your shell configuration (probably `~/.bashrc`):

```
export VISUAL=vim
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"
```

Comment: Not working for me! I still see a number after: "sudo crontab -e" instead of editing crontab!

Comment: @MohsenAbasi What do you mean “I still see a number?”. Check that `EDITOR` is in both your environment (`env | grep EDITOR`) and is passed to `sudo` (`sudo env | grep EDITOR`), as your system’s sudo security policy may prohibit it (see `man sudo` for more details).

Comment: I mean that I still see just a number (not opening 'vim' editor) after executing: 'sudo crontab -e'. Since there is no default editor for editing cron jobs in my Ubuntu. To have a default editor, your solution does nothing for me. Only solution of 'DobesVandermeer' works.

Comment: Once it is done, reload the config with `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I had to use `/usr/bin/vi` rather than `vim` otherwise `crontab -e` failed with the error `crontab /bin/sh: 1: vim: not found`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall given this is such a noob question it's probably a good idea to point out that a restart of `bash` or `source ~/.bashrc`, whatever, is required to update the environment after you've edited the file. As Jona points out.

Answer (score 177):

On Ubuntu and other Ubuntu/Debian-based Linux systems, you can explicitly set the default text editor at the system level by providing its path to `update-alternatives`:

## Automatic, Scripted

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/vim.basic
sudo update-alternatives --set vi /usr/bin/vim.basic
```

### Note

If your distro doesn't call it `/usr/bin/vim.basic`, you can find out which path to use with the `--list` argument:

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --list editor
```

```
/bin/ed
/bin/nano
/usr/bin/vim.basic
/usr/bin/vim.tiny
```

## Manual, Interactive

Or, to see all options and choose interactively:

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

Comment: This set the default for `git` too, which was exactly what I needed.

Comment: This set the default for `ranger` too, which was exactly what I needed. 
PS: just for helping index for people who is trying to do the same.

Comment: Only this worked for me on Ubuntu server 18.04

Comment: Not within FreeBSD https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=update-alternatives&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.2-RELEASE but within the port of dkpg https://www.freshports.org/archivers/dpkg/

Comment: This works with my version of WSL2/Ubuntu on Windows 10.

Answer (score 45):

In recent versions of Ubuntu you use the [alternatives system](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) to manage the default, editor, e.g.:

```
update-alternatives --set editor /usr/bin/vim.basic
```

To see which editors are available for use:

```
update-alternatives --list editor
```

Some UNIX distributions might provide a `select-editor` command:

```
select-editor
```

And it will ask you which editor to use.

Make sure you actually have `vim` installed before trying to set it as your default editor.

Comment: That shows a list of editors but it doesn't allow me to change anything (At least on 18.04).

Comment: Linux only? https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=select-editor

Comment: `select-editor` command not found on `mac`.

Comment: This is different to what's asked - alternatives apply to _all users_, not just one.

Answer (score 3):

If bash is your shell, then insert it into `.bash_profile` in your home directory; if zsh is your shell, then insert it into `.zprofile`; for other shells see the according documentation.

Comment: On zsh I recommend putting it into `.zshenv` instead.

Comment: @pepoluan If you see this, could you please elaborate? The `.zprofile` file will be read for each and every shell invocation. It seems odd to want to set the editor for shell sessions that aren't even interactive.

Comment: @Kusalananda it's just setting an env var anyways, so not harmful. If you need to, say `su` into your account, `.zshenv` will be sourced.

Comment: Why not put it in `.zshrc` for `zsh` as the top-vote opts for `.bashrc`?

Comment: You shouldn't go around putting it into things like that.