# How to change default text editor for virsh edit?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, editors, libvirt, virsh

I recently installed virt-manager on Arch Linux, and unlike under Ubuntu, I was not prompted to choose a text editor on the first launch of virsh-edit. Instead, the XML file was opened in vi (or vim, not sure).

[From this thread in the RedHat archives](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2016-July/msg00020.html), I thought that if I just added to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano
```

that would solve the problem. **But setting EDITOR environment variable didn't work.**

Also, launching it with `EDITOR=geany sudo virsh edit myWINVM` gave the same result, as did trying to use a different editor: `EDITOR=geany sudo virsh edit myWINVM` [as described here](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/FAQ)

and I see that the variable has in fact been set:

```
[~]$ printenv
SHELL=/bin/bash
SESSION_MANAGER=local/virtland:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/5451,unix/virtland:/tmp/.ICE-unix/5451
WINDOWID=27262979
COLORTERM=truecolor
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=xfce-
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-j36TZui4fOt5/agent.5457
DESKTOP_SESSION=Xfce Session
SSH_AGENT_PID=5458
EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano
...
```

However `virsh edit MYVM` still opens the XML in vi.

Is there something different I need to do in Arch? Has the method of changing this setting been changed in recent updates of virsh?

Comment: Is the path correct? My nano is `/bin/nano`.

Comment: Yes, ```/usr/bin/nano``` opens nano. I also have it at /bin/nano. Both paths have the same effect.

Comment: Did you try exporting `VISUAL` instead? See [How can I set "vi" as my default editor in UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73486/423679) and [VISUAL vs. EDITOR – what’s the difference?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4859/423679)

Answer (score 4):

I had to [add the editor to sudoers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#Configuration) by putting `Defaults editor=/bin/nano` at the end of /etc/sudoers AND THEN I could use `sudo EDITOR=nano virsh edit myWINVM`.

Update: at a later time, I got it working by adding `export EDITOR=nano` to `/etc/environment`.

Comment: I'm not sure how the sudoers change (of `editor`) solved your problem, since that's only the editor that `visudo` will use, and should have no bearing on virsh's EDITOR value.

Comment: You might have better luck with a sudoers change of `env_keep += "EDITOR"`

Comment: Just to add, I encountered this problem again and now changing the visudo editor in `/etc/sudoers` has no effect. Still looking for a permanent solution.

Comment: OK, I got it working by adding `export EDITOR=nano` to ` /etc/environment` .

Comment: `/etc/environment` isn't a shell file, `export` has no business there.

Comment: EDITOR=nano to /etc/environment works

Answer (score 4):

Remove the file `~/.selected_editor`, and `virsh` will prompt you for the editor to use.  Probably, that's the one in `/root`, since one needs admin privilege to use `virsh`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sudo -E virsh edit myWINVM
```

The `-E` flag will preserve your current user's environment variables
when running as root, so as long as you have `EDITOR` exported
in your user's environment, then it will be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `virsh` with `sudo`, the `/root` is the directory the configuration applies to.

Just some remarks: the solution above works fine. And code does not just run out of the box when selected. So this seems to be the works choice for `virsh` when used together with `sudo`.

```bsh
sudo cat .selected_editor
```

So the result looks like

```bsh
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/code"
```

Change it and retry, - or as said above.