# Command for the default in-terminal text editor

Tags: editors, defaults

I often see instructions that include `vim` or `nano`, meaning to open the file in that step in your text editor of choice. Is there an agnostic command I can use in place of the specific program that would open the input in the user's default in-terminal text editor, whether it's `vim`, `nano`, or something else?

I see `editor` mentioned in the Similar Questions sidebar—is that still limited to Debian-based distros? And is there any alternative?

Comment: Related, not exactly a duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/visual-vs-editor-whats-the-difference

Comment: in Debian you can also configure the program executed when you call "editor" by executing once: "update-alternatives --config editor". There you can select the one you prefer (default is nano). This will e.g. make so that when you press "v" in less you get the editor you want, so you can switch from nano to vi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use  `$EDITOR`, provided that it's been defined:

```
$EDITOR filename.txt
```

But I think most docs use `nano` because if someone's blindly following along, it's a safe bet to use. If the user has decided they actually prefer one editor over another, they'll know enough to replace it with `vim`, `emacs`, etc themselves.

`edit` may work well on Debian-based systems, but on others it invokes `ex`, which isn't recommended.

Comment: `$EDITOR` only makes sense if it's defined. Invoking `ed` hardly counts as standard and is abysmal in terms of user-friendliness. `edit` is perfectly fine on Debian, but may invoke vi on other systems (where does it invoke ex?).

Comment: Gilles: You're right, it only makes sense if it's been defined. It was the closest thing to a "universal" command per the OP's question. "Ed is the standard" is an old joke, since it's the one defined in the POSIX standard (see "man ed" or Google "Ed is the standard" for more info). I don't know about "edit" on other systems, but mine invokes ex (Arch Linux), so it can't be considered universal.

Comment: POSIX also defines vi. Jokes are fine, but don't present them as something serious — *I*'ve heard that one before but your target audience hasn't.

Answer (score 5):

If the environment variable `VISUAL` is set, use that.

Otherwise, if the environment variable `EDITOR` is set, use that.

Otherwise, Unix tradition defaults to `vi`. This is not at all user-friendly — people who use vi know how to set up their system to invoke it, your application should be friendly to those users who don't. Unfortunately there's no good, portable way to find a decent editor. You can try [`xdg-mime query default`](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-mime.html), but even where the utility is available, it doesn't always work. On Debian and Debian-like systems, invoke [`sensible-editor`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sensible-editor.1.html), which does all that stuff for you — but I don't know of anything like it on other Unix variants.

This yields code like

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$VISUAL" ]; then
  exec $VISUAL "$@"
elif [ -n "$EDITOR" ]; then
  exec $EDITOR "$@"
elif type sensible-editor >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
  exec sensible-editor "$@"
elif cmd=$(xdg-mime query default ) 2>/dev/null; [ -n "$cmd" ]; then
  exec "$cmd" "$@"
else
  editors='nano joe vi'
  if [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
    editors="gedit kate $editors"
  fi
  for x in $editors; do
    if type "$x" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
      exec "$x" "$@"
    fi
  done
fi
```

Most programs do whitespace splitting on `$VISUAL` and `$EDITOR`, but not all.

Comment: Note that `sensible-editor` _itself_ incorporates the environment variable lookups and fallbacks, so if `sensible-editor` exists one need not do pretty much any of the other stuff, and one uses it _in place of_ your script rather than _as part of_ it.  Conversely, if `sensible-editor` does not exist, and the environment variables do not exist, the `editor` controlled by Debian's/RedHat's "alternatives"  system is a better fallback than hardwired names.  http://jdebp.uk./FGA/unix-editors-and-pagers.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bash, which is the default terminal language for all linux distros (as far as I'm aware), there is something called environmental variables. Many of these variables are set up by your distribution, where some need to be set or 'exported' manually. $EDITOR is one in particular (need caps and dollar sign).  The dollar sign signifies the variable being called on, and the caps signify that its an environmental variable. $HOME is a common env. variable which is shorthanded by ~.

So to answer your questions succinctly, the command you would run to use a users default editor edit file.txt

```
$EDITOR file.txt
```

To set or export the default editor to vim put this in the user's $HOME/.bashrc file:

```
export EDITOR=/bin/vim
```

then run:

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

If the $EDITOR variable is not set, then there really isn't a default editor.

As far as alternatives go, there are infinitely many by aliases:

```
Alias E="$EDITOR"
```

After being sourcing the .bashrc file, this would allow me to run the first command above by:

```
E text.vim
```

However, don't get too carried away with aliases, as they can be a major hinderence towards more advanced bash usage.

---

Another useful and similar environmental variable is $PAGER, which can be used to open the default program for document viewing.

```
$PAGER file.txt
```

The usual default for this env variable is "less."

Comment: (1) bash isn’t a “terminal language,” it’s a shell, also known as a command-line interpreter (CLI).  (2) I believe that pretty much *every* shell in use these days supports environment variables, so you don’t really need to caveat that.  On the other hand, there are some shells that don’t understand the `export` command, and I’m not sure about `source` and `alias`.  (3) `alias` must be in lower case (unless you have defined an alias for `Alias`).

Comment: Probably a better way of putting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler version of [Giles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317068/77539) that could be inlined to launch the editor in a line of script could be something like:

```
command ${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-$(command -v vi)}} $file
```

(This would need tweaking to get it to work with default editor arguments, though, like when `EDITOR="emacs -nw"`.  The `exec` calls in the linked answer have this issue as well.  `command` may be a bit safer than `exec`.)