# How to start Vim in insert mode at end of first line when committing Git changes?

Tags: vim, configuration, git

What would be the best way to set Vim up to always **put the cursor in insert mode at the end of the first line** (to account for commit message templates) when running `git commit`? This would basically do something identical to pressing <kbd>ggA</kbd> every time. Ideally this should be a Vim configuration (presumably in [~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Always_start_on_first_line_of_git_commit_message)), because I rely on [`$VISUAL`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4861/3645) rather than configuring editors for everything separately.

---

This almost works:

```
call feedkeys('ggA', 'int')
```

However, when running `echo 'some text' >/tmp/COMMIT_EDITMSG && vim -Nu NONE --cmd 'filetype plugin on' /tmp/COMMIT_EDITMSG` the cursor is on the status line until I press something:

[image: Vim with missing cursor]

---

`1 | startinsert!` works for `echo 'some text' >/tmp/COMMIT_EDITMSG && vim -Nu NONE --cmd 'filetype plugin on' /tmp/COMMIT_EDITMSG`, but when running `git commit -t /tmp/COMMIT_EDITMSG` it breaks completely - the commit message is not shown and the commit template is shown below the status line:

[image: <code>git commit</code> broken view]

After pressing right arrow the commit message and cursor shows up, and the editor is in insert mode, but the cursor is at the second character rather than at the end of line:

[image: <code>git commit</code> after moving cursor]

Do I need to add something to the configuration to tell Vim to show the actual contents of the buffer?

Comment: Do you have a line in your config that activates this behaviour for all files? If so, you could make an exception for git.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have [to configure it](https://bitbucket.org/jasonwryan/shiv/src/10918a6d8eb1347cbc3bdf07bb37ef2955b4835e/.vimrc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#.vimrc-95) as it does [not ship like that](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/archlinux.vim?h=packages/vim).

Comment: I'll cheat: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Always_start_on_first_line_of_git_commit_message - you can adjust the actual postion on the line to fit your default line length (presumably 78).

Comment: That's the page I got the idea from :) I wanted to make it work exactly like pressing `ggA` every time I commit. It's really frustrating how I can't just put that string in a configuration file, but instead have to learn a completely and weirdly documented new language.

Comment: @user938271 That's weird: It works, but the cursor is invisible before I start typing or moving it somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adapting one of the autocommands given in the Vim Wikia, this seems to work fine with `git commit -t /tmp/COMMIT_EDITMSG` for me:

```
" ~/.vim/ftplugin/gitcommit.vim
au! VimEnter COMMIT_EDITMSG exec 'norm gg' | startinsert!
```

I used `exec 'norm gg' |` instead `1 |` because `:1 |` is equivalent to `:1p |` and there's a small delay as the line is printed.

Comment: Fantastic! It's weird how such a simple command is so hard to automate.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell git to invoke vim with the `startinsert` command. Put this in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export GIT_EDITOR="vim -c 'startinsert'"
```

But be warned that having to press escape when you have to commit a merge gets annoying, because there's already a generated commit message for those.

Comment: ah nice way to make it like annoying is using alt, `alt+:` has the same effect as pressing `:` in normal mode~