# Why can I not do visual mode when using visudo?

Tags: vim, sudo

I thought perhaps `vim` was in some compatibility mode of some sort. To make sure it was using `vim` instead of `vi`, I set the `VISUAL` environment variable but was still unable to get into visual mode (hitting the <kbd>v</kbd> key).

Any suggestions?

Comment: See the [Caveat Section of the Sudoers man page](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html) to understand why jofel's answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I am, however, unsure how the caveat section was relevant. Are you emphasizing the security concerns?

Comment: "The sudoers file should always be edited by the visudo command which locks the file and does grammatical checking. It is imperative that sudoers be free of syntax errors since sudo will not run with a syntactically incorrect sudoers file."  My Two Cents: visudo uses a base text editor w/ no visual mode in order to keep those permission checks etc as clean as possible,  therefore it ignores the environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, `visudo` ignores the `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` variable for security reasons and calls `vi`, so the compatibility mode of `vim` is enabled.

Read [How to set visudo to use a different editor than the default on Fedora?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4408/how-to-set-visudo-to-use-a-different-editor-than-the-default-on-fedora) to change the default editor.