# Now visudo won't work at all

Tags: linux, rhel, sudo, sudoedit

RHEL 5.10

When I do `visudo` I get this error:

```
chuck 75->visudo
visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

Listing of sudo exe file and /etc/sudoers:

```
chuck 76->ls -l /etc/sudo*
-r--r----- 1 root root 3540 May  9 11:44 /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- 1 root root 3401 Aug 12  2014 /etc/sudoers.20140812

chuck 273->ls -l `which sudo`
-rwsr-xr-x 2 root root 182040 Mar  4  2014 /usr/bin/sudo

chuck 275->ls -l `which visudo`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 98576 Mar  4  2014 /usr/sbin/visudo
```

As you can see my /etc/sudoers.20140812 backup file has the same permissions as the actual /etc/sudoers file. So I don't know what's up.

- Just before this happened I changed my environment var in my .cshrc VISUAL to: `setenv VISUAL /usr/bin/nano`.
- I've tried in the shell `unset VISUAL` but I still get "permission denied" error.
- I've tried in the shell `setenv VISUAL` but that didn't work. When I did `visudo` I still get "permission denied on /etc/sudoers".
- I also logged that shell window off and logged into a new one and still get "permission denied" when I do `visudo`.
- I tried googling the answer and tried a few things but that didn't work.
- Searching stackexchange didn't show any past questions either.

---

TRIED: Another thing I tried and the error message.

```
chuck 59->sudo chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0640, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

TRIED: Making an alias I called `editsudo`: `alias editsudo 'sudo chmod 770 /etc/sudoers; sudo nedit /etc/sudoers; sudo chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers'`

```
chuck 62->editsudo
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0640, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0640, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: /etc/sudoers is mode 0640, should be 0440
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per `man visudo`, section "Diagnostics":

> ```
>  /etc/sudoers.tmp: Permission denied
>        You didn’t run visudo as root.
> ```

I see nothing in your post to indicate that you *did* run it as root.

Try `sudo visudo`.

Also it looks like you may be getting errors related to `sudo` itself.  Can you `sudo ls ~root` successfully?

---

You may also want to review the man page, as:

> ```
>  There is a hard-coded list of one or more editors that visudo will use
>  set at compile-time that may be overridden via the editor sudoers Default
>  variable.  This list defaults to /usr/local/bin/vi.  Normally, visudo
>  does not honor the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables unless they
>  contain an editor in the aforementioned editors list.
> ```

The man page proceeds to describe ways to work around this, but you should be aware of the security implications of doing so.  I would advice you to just learn `vi` since it is both ubiquitous and extremely powerful.  (Start by running `vimtutor`; set aside half an hour for this.)

Comment: Well, that was it. I did `sudo visudo`. Before just `visudo` worked but I'm not sure why. I thought the `sudo` command was part of the `visudo` editor. And changing the editor was another thing I was going to do but visudo was ignoring the EDITOR and VISUAL env vars.

Comment: For others: [How to change editor for visudo](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4408/how-to-set-visudo-to-use-a-different-editor-than-the-default-on-fedora). It worked for me.